# mfc, How can I declare an object with parameter "this" in a class?

Tags: class, object, constructor

How can I declare an object with parameter `this` in a class like this?
the object `Something` doesn't have a default constructor.
I know I can do it with a pointer.

But is there any way to declare it as a value type?

```
class MyClass
{
public:
   Something sth(this);

};
```

Comment: Learn some C++ before asking questions here.

Comment: @kotlomoy All I read from your comment was 'go away'. Also, you're making a lot of assumptions what the OP is motivated to do after reading your comment. I'd probably simply go away. You could have written 'Please clarify' or 'You might be stuck here with very basic problems, please consider reading <link to manual>'. But all you did was offend the OP. But maybe that's just me.